# Shortcut in eclipse to do the opposite of tab?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

[image]

Is there a shortcut or option in eclipse that will perform the opposite of tab. I can select a bunch of lines and if i do control tab, all of those lines will be tabbed over. Is there a control option that I can do to do the opposite of that? Is there a shortcut to get all of your code to line up? I looked on http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html but didn't find anything. It's a hassle to go to each line and hit back a bunch of times....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move selected lines to the left.

You could also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format the whole file.